# quadcc: integrand F must return a single, real-valued vector

Tags: integration, octave

```
 h = @(x) 1./sqrt((-3/2).*exp(-2) +2.*exp(-x)) 
 Th1 = quadcc(h, 2, 2.2877)
```

The above code gives me the following error message:

> error: `quadcc`: integrand `F` must return a single, real-valued vector
>   error: called from
>       ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍`ex11_1` at line 26 column 4

Answer (score 0):

The argument of the sqrt must be positive which is the case in [2,2-ln(3/4)].
But 2-ln(3/4) is approx 2.287682072.., but the integral which is calculated covers more ( 2-ln(3/4) < 2.2877), so you integrate a bit in the area where the arg of sqrt gets negative.

Comment: The integrand becomes complex outside this bound.

Comment: (O.o) Maybe because the message is "integrand F must return a single, real-valued vector"? Please note that Complex numbers generally are not Reals, but Reals are always Complex as well.